# SQL: Creating time intervals between rows

Tags: mysql, sql, intervals

I'm rather stuck on how to transform my table (using `MySQL`). Let me start by describing my table.

`ID, ObservationDate(DATETIME), Total score`, whole bunch of parameters that determine the total score

The ID's stand for patients, each ID may occur multiple times on different observation dates. I want to add **3 new columns**: `t_start, t_end, t_total`

`T_start`: would be 0 for the very first observation or the previous observations' `ObservationDate`

`T_end`: is the current observation date

`T_Total`: Total time elapsed since start until last observation date.

These columns would have to be in LONG format, so preferably in hours.

Any idea on how to do this?

Kind regards

As I'm getting downvoted and this is being requested:

Edit: Getting downvoted and people seem to require more info. Here we go:
Table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `dataset_origineel` (
      PatientId` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `ObservationDate` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `EWS_Total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,)
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Data set:

```
INSERT INTO `dataset_origineel` (`PatientId`, `ObservationDate`, `EWS_Total`) VALUES
(30, '2019-05-01 13:27:50.0000000',0)
(30, '2019-05-01 15:27:44.0000000',5)
(30, '2019-05-01 15:54:27.0000000',4)
(30, '2019-05-01 16:07:27.0000000',2)
(31, '2019-05-01 17:03:16.0000000',1)
(31, '2019-05-01 18:02:29.0000000',0)
(31, '2019-05-01 19:23:49.0000000',0)
(32, '2019-05-01 21:07:36.0000000',0)
(32, '2019-05-01 21:08:05.0000000',4)
(32, '2019-05-01 21:12:11.0000000',3)
(32, '2019-05-01 21:13:21.0000000',2)
(32, '2019-05-01 23:12:50.0000000',0)
(32, '2019-05-02 00:28:57.0000000',3)
```

What I want is:

```
PatientId, ObservationDate,      t_start, t_end, t_total
30         2019-05-01 13:27:50      0      120     170
30         2019-05-01 15:27:44      120    147     170
30         2019-05-01 15:54:27      147    170     170
30         2019-05-01 16:07:27      170            170
```

And so on. Hope this is more clear.

Also: Thanks to people helping with the formatting, rather new to SO as a whole )

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Have added an MCRE, thanks to everyone for help with the formatting.

Comment: why is  t_start 0 for -05-01 19:23,  when there is an earlier row -05-01 15:27 ?  why is t_total 2.5 (and not 2) on that row ? and why is t_total 3.7 on the other row ? either the data shown is wonky and doesn't accurately reflect what you want, or the rules for deriving these values is significantly more convoluted than the simple description.

Comment: Nope, you are right. I quickly drew it up to illustrate a point but I should've chosen the values better. I'll change it now.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
    lag(observationdate) over(partition by id order by observationdate) as t_start,
    observationdate as t_end,
    timestampdiff(
        second, 
        lag(observationdate) over(partition by id order by observationdate),
        observationdate
    ) / 60 / 60 as t_total
from mytable t
```

This window function is available in MySQL 8.0.

Note that I computed the time difference in seconds, then translated it to hours. This gives you a decimal count of hours, which is more accurate that giving argument `hour` to `timestampdif()` (this function just counts the number of unit boundaries that where crossed between the two timestamps).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. I have, however, run into an error using this code. I swapped out id to PatientId and mytable to the name of my table and have run into the following error:
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, null given

Comment: @Thorniey: that's a PHP error, it has nothing to do with this SQL code. you should probably try and run query in your SQL client first (phpmyadmin, dbweaver, whatever you are using) to validate that it works fine. Reminder: this requires version 8.0 of MySQL.